# Comparision of data between two sheets, and print yes or no

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, multiple-columns

I have range of data in one sheet with in different rows say A1 to A100, B1 to B1000 I need to compare this data with another sheet like.... A1-A100 from sheet-1 with C1-C100, d1-d100,e1-e100...

[image]

If cell value of a1 match with c1/d1/e1 (or condition) then "Yes" has to be printed in f1 in sheet-2 else no has to be printed in f1.... I have a v look up formula for this... But now I want to write a vba code

V-Lookup for comparing the data from two workbooks

```
IF(OR(ISNA(VLOOKUP(F2,'[Value Sets.xlsx]Value Sets'!$AE$2:$AE$130,1,FALSE))=FALSE,
ISNA(VLOOKUP(L2,'[Value Sets.xlsx]Value Sets'!$AE$2:$AE$130,1,FALSE))=FALSE,
ISNA(VLOOKUP(M2,'[Value Sets.xlsx]Value Sets'!$AE$2:$AE$130,1,FALSE))=FALSE,
ISNA(VLOOKUP(E2,'[Value Sets.xlsx]Value Sets'!$AE$2:$AE$130,1,FALSE))=FALSE),"Yes","No")
```

I tried a sample code to do Comparison of two rows from different work sheets:
But it is considering the two rows at one go and printing the distinct values

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Select
    For Each rngCell In Range("F2", Range("F2").End(xlDown))
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Valuesets").Select
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)), rngCell) = 0 Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Select
            Range("AB" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = rngCell
        End If
    Next
 MsgBox "Execution completed
```

But I want to do the comparison of A1 of sheet -1 with A:A os sheet-2 and print "Yes"/"No" in b1 of sheet-1 then do with a2(sheet-1) with(A:A) sheet-2 and print result in b2(sheet-1)

Comparing data in two rows from two sheets in different ranges and print result in another row:

[image: Comparing data in two rows from two sheets in different ranges and print result in another row]

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Either construct your sentences in a better way or show an example (screenshot, spreadsheet). Do you want to compare `A1:A100` in both sheets? Are the ranges the same in every sheet, just values could be different?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer... I believe that we figured out a route to solving the problem....... :) (y)

```
Sub sbWriteIntoCellData()

     ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Select

     For Each rngCell In Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown))
         If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B2", Range("B2").End(xlDown)), rngCell) = 0 Then
             Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = "Yes"
             Else: Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = "No"
         End If
     Next
     MsgBox "Execution completed"

End Sub
```

The above code will compare two rows and publish the results in the same sheet...
Now, I am trying to refine it in a way such the code has to ignore the blank cells and find the last cell and then do the comparison- and also the comparison from different sheets